# how I can display Flash animations in Swing components?

Tags: java, eclipse, flash, swing

I am trying to develop an application with eclipse (java swing) and I wonder if I can add Flash animations in the JButton or JPanel

Comment: Not without extreme effort as far as I know. You're probably best off avoiding attempting this.

Comment: But then Google has lead to this link: [jflash](http://java.net/projects/jflash/), but I have no idea how good it is or if it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [DJ sweet from DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html), its last release is 2011-07-02.

Here is [a screenshot](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet/screenshots/images/FlashPlayer.png).

You can dowload it from [its sourceforge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject/files/DJ%20Sweet/).

Comment: This is an [example](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet/screenshots/images/FlashPlayer.png) of the project in action.

Comment: Yes. You have to download the zip file of the last version (now it is 1.0.1) and extract it. Inside you will find a jar containing the library and a jar with some examples.