# How to add a flash animation in java desktop application

Tags: java, flash

In my java program I would like to add an animated logo in some of the user interfaces. I used this code but it does not work . I have added the jflashplayer jar also . sill it does not work. can some one suggest a solution ?

```
try {
    FlashPanel fp = new FlashPanel(new File("C:\\Users\\ASHAN\\Desktop\\grandmsz.swf"));
    jPanel1.add(fp);
    fp.isOpaque();
    fp.play();
} catch (JFlashLibraryLoadFailedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (JFlashInvalidFlashException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054884/how-i-can-display-flash-animations-in-swing-components

Comment: Another approach would be to use an AVI, animated GIF or a mPNG.